# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web3-eth-personal'

Tags: contract-development

I have these two lines of code to unlock the default account,
But i keep on getting error , tough the require path points to proper directory of web3-eth-personal,

```
var personal = require('./node_modules/web3-eth-personal/');
personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
```

The Error:

> web3.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module
>   './node_modules/web3-eth-personal/'
>           at o (web3.min.js:1)
>           at o (web3.min.js:1)
>           at Index2.html:49

The thing is that iam able to call a function which reads value from contract, but trying to set value in contract is problem. my contract is on Ropsten test network.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
npm install web3-eth-account --save

npm install web3-eth-personal --save

npm install web3 --save

var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');
var Personal = require('web3-eth-personal');
var Web3 = require('web3');

var accounts = new Accounts(Constant.ETHnodeURL.connectETHnodeWS);
var personal = new Personal(Constant.ETHnodeURL.connectETHnodeWS);
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(Constant.ETHnodeURL.connectETHnodeWS));

web3.eth.personal.newAccount('privatepassword').then((data) => {
   console.log('Address:'+data);
});
```

Comment: this line npm install web3-eth-account --save  shows this error npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: web3-eth-account@latest

Comment: check your node version, It should be graeter than 9>

Comment: I am having a simple contract Employee where there are two functions, setEmployee and GetEmployee, i am not able to call setEmployee, i am using a simple webform to update the employee, details, do you have any sample application which does something like this?

Comment: its 8.9.4, do not want to install the other version as of now..thanks for help, i

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73169/discussion-on-answer-by-kunvar-singh-uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-web3-et).

Comment: It should be `npm install web3-eth-accounts`